# Variable array declaration

Tags: c, arrays

Consider the C code below:

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main()
{int n,i;
scanf("%d",&n); 
int a[n]; //Why doesn't compiler give an error here?
}
```

How can I declare an array when the compiler doesn't know initially?

Comment: Why do you think it should give you a error? It would be a error in C++, but in C it's not.

Comment: Because in the 1999 C standard, it is a valid construct - look up variable length array.   It is optional in the 2011 C standard, but compilers are permitted to support it.

Comment: for the same reason because array initialisation gives an error

Comment: Can you show the code that gives you the error?

Comment: if i initialise a[n] = {0};

Comment: A VLA cannot be initialised using normal array initialisation syntax.   That syntax requires the number of elements in the array to be known to the compiler.   The whole point of a VLA is that the number of elements is determined at run time (in this case, based on the value of `n` read by the preceding `scanf()`).

Answer (score 0):

When the the exact size of array is unknown until compile time, you need to use dynamic memory allocation. In the C standard library, there are functions for dynamic memory allocation: malloc, realloc, calloc and free.

These functions can be found in the `<stdlib.h>` header file.

If you want to create an array you do:

```
int array[10];
```

In dynamic memory allocation you do:

```
int *array = malloc(10 * sizeof(int));
```

In your case is:

```
int *array = malloc(n * sizeof(int));
```

If you allocate a memory position, never forget to deallocate:

```
if(array != NULL)
  free(array);
```

Memory allocation is a complex subject, I suggest you search for the subject because my answer was simple. You can start with this link:

https://www.programiz.com/c-programming/c-dynamic-memory-allocation

Comment: "When the the exact size of array is unknown until compile time" -- did you mean unknown until run-time? In any case, this is wrong. Variable length arrays were introduced into Standard C with C99. Though they were made optional with C11, they are still widely supported and available.